# postgreSQL query to get the time difference per person

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been at this for hours and I can't figure out how to correctly do this.

I have the following table

```
name    date
Clara   2017-07-16
Clara   2017-07-22
Mike    2017-07-07
Mike    2017-07-12
Mike    2017-07-18
```

I'm trying to figure out the average date difference per person so that

Clara returns 6 ((2017-07-22 -  2017-07-16)/1) and

Mike returns 5.5 ((2017-07-18 -  2017-07-12) + (2017-07-12 -  2017-07-07)/2)

```
name    date
Clara   6
Mike    5.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a window function to calculate the date difference between two subsequent dates for a `"name"` and then you can calculate the average.

Here is a good tutorial on using window functions [from the postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) for further reading.

```
WITH datediffs AS (
SELECT 
    "name"
  , EXTRACT('day' FROM date - LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY "name" ORDER BY "date")) diff
FROM raw_data
)
SELECT "name", avg(diff) avg_difference
FROM datediffs
GROUP By 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need window functions for this.  The average time difference is the total difference divided by the number of observations minus one.  So:

```
select name,
       (max(date) - min(date) ) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from following_table t
group by name;
```

Comment: yup, more elegant solution than using a window function